# calling a procedure in another Oracle database from PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In **database A** I have written a PL/SQL procedure called `is_document_valid`. From this procedure I would like to call another PL/SQL procedure in **database B**. Something like this:

```
procedure is_document_valid( p_url varchar2( 200 ) )
    -- call stored-procedure in another database
    check_document( p_url );
end;
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you really mean "*database*" (as in seperate server and instance) or do you mean "schema" (as in different user in the same Oracle installation)

Comment: The former. A completely separate server and instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You append the database name you're calling the procedure from onto the end of the procedure name:

```
procedure is_document_valid( p_url varchar2( 200 ) )
    -- call stored-procedure in another database
    check_document@some_other_db( p_url );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This looks like the right answer. I suppose all I need to do is set up the database link but once that is done your answer is perfect.